# Can't upload image file with php to sever

Tags: php, html, sql

I've created a form in html, for upload image, it seems work perfect because when I upload the image it give me the string "Success", but i can't find the file in the server.

this is my code:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

      $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }

      if($file_size > 2097152){
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
        }

      if(empty($errors)==true){
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"./photo/".$file_name);
         echo "Success";
      }
      else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
?>

       <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="image" />
     <input type="submit"/>

     <ul>
        <li>Sent file: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['name'];  ?>
        <li>File size: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['size'];  ?>
        <li>File type: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['type'] ?>
     </ul>

  </form>
```

Comment: Check if the directory `./photo` lies in the same folder as of PHP uploading script. Check permissions of `./photos` directory.

Comment: In what directory do you expect it to be? Should be in a directory "photo" relative to the script. Can you print the content of $file_name?

Comment: @Amarnasan yes I can print it , it give me : roma-fiumicino4.jpg , so the name of the image

Comment: Check in the temp folder, I could be there since you have not specify a exact place

Comment: Can you see the contents of the directory "photo" that should be in the same directory of the script?

Comment: @Pupil I have this directory : SREFCloud/poi/photo, I want to put files in photo and I have the index.php file in SREFCloud

Comment: @Dinidu where is the temp folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check move_uploaded_file:

```
$ret_value = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"./photo/".$file_name);

if ($ret_value == false) die ("Ups! Couldn't actually move the temp file! No success at all.");
```

If it is returning false (error) the file could not be being actually moved from the temp file and you still would get the "Success" message, because no exception would arise.

If you're getting an error, maybe you can fix it by moving the file to the actual existing directory.

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"./poi/photo/".$file_name);
```

Comment: Ok, but at least you know whether the move_uploaded_file returned true or false?

Comment: Ok, now you have more information: you know the file is uploaded to your server, but there is an error when trying to move it from the temporary directory to the final destination. Work on that. Check whether the directory actually exists, and check whether the server user (usually apache, or www-user) has the privileges to create files in that directory.

Comment: I check the privileges and it is all ok, also the directory, but I haven't a temporary directory, where I can see it or where I need to create it?

Comment: In the parameter upload_tmp_dir of php.ini. But you are are already successfully uploading the file, that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: You shouldn't set the content of the variable upload_tmp_dir. Why are you so sure that the web server can create new files in the directory? How did you check it?

Comment: Because I have tried also to use other directory and it dosen't work

Comment: Two wrongs don't prove one right. Do you even know how to check the user, usergroup and access privileges of the directory?. Because if not, you have another kind of problem.

Comment: ok, I edited permission for "poi" and "photo" folders and when I upload the image it return now true , but the image isn't store in the server

Comment: If the move_uploaded_file returned true, but you can't see the file in the directory where it has been uploaded, then I'm absolutely lost, sorry.

Comment: But then the file has been uploaded to the server! Shouldn't you close this question and start a new one like "Why can't filezilla see files I successfully uploaded through PHP" ?

Answer (score 0):

Your image upload is clearing every validation.

But, you are not storing it at correct paths:

Change:

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"./photo/".$file_name);
```

To:

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"./poi/photo/".$file_name);
```

Also, apply write permissions for the directory `poi`.